# Stack data using JAVA SWING

Tags: java, swing, stack

I am trying to use stacks in java swing. The problem is that I can't show the stacks in a  text area because it always shows only the first letter.

I know how to use stacks and queues but my problem is using it in swing

If I print the stack in the console it works fine.

```
Stack<String> stacksGUI = new Stack<>();

//Button to add data into a stack
 stacksGUI.push(inputTxt.getText());
        inputTxt.setText("");
        inputTxt.requestFocus();

//Button to show data in a textArea
      while (!stacksGUI.empty()) {      
      outputTxt.setText(stacksGUI.pop()+" ");
                    }
```

Comment: [`setText(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) doesn't append to the existing text, it replaces it.  You need to create your entire output, then call `setText(String)` once on the final `String`.

Comment: Is the `outputTxt` component sized correctly?  Are you using a layout manager?  If so, which one?  I assume you only want one of the stack elements to show at a time?  We're gonna need a lot more information in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it always shows only the first letter.

```
while (!stacksGUI.empty()) {      
   outputTxt.setText(stacksGUI.pop()+" ");
```

The `setText(...)` replaces the existing text so you will only see the last text popped from the `Stack`.

Use the `append(...)` method of the `JTextArea` to append text with existing text.